# How can I get the IP address of my local machine the .NET 3.5 way?

Tags: .net-3.5, ip-address

I've found a **ton** of tutorials, however they are all very old for 1.1 or 2.0; there must be an easier way now with .NET 3.5.

Care to share? :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has changed; the old way is still the only way to do it.